# Google Sheets add-on with custom functions not running

Tags: google-sheets, user-defined-functions, add-on

I have written an add-on for Google Sheets that contains some custom functions. This has been working fine for months, but suddenly today it started have problems for some spreadsheets. The problem we're seeing is that the custom functions are not running at all, they just show `Loading...` forever.

I've done a lot of we searching, but none of the suggestions have helped in this case. I've also tried a lot of investigation and the most notable point I've found is that it seems these functions are not running at all. I'm determining that by looking at the Apps Script Execution Logs. For the cases when the functions works I see these custom functions in the log as `Completed`, but for the cases when it does not there is no log entry at all (no error or anything).

I should clarify that the problem seems to be spreadsheet related. That is, the functions work fine in some spreadsheet, but don't work in others. Also, my add on exposes multiple custom functions, and when this problem is happening it happens for all of the functions.

Furthermore, I've seen that this problem sometimes happens in a freshly created empty spreadsheet, but other times it is fine.

As I mentioned above, everything has been working fine for months, so I don't think it is a bug with my functions.

Is anyone else seeing problems like this? Does anyone have suggestions on how to investigate further? Any other ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to star [issue 222342097](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097) in the issue tracker. Click the star icon ☆ in the top left-hand corner to vote for fixing the issue and get notified of status changes. Please do not post a "me too" or "+1" reply, but just click the star icon. Google prioritizes issues with the most stars.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that issue. It looks slightly different, but quite similar, so I did star it. I also think it's interesting there is a comment from someone else saying the problem seems much worse since yesterday, which is my situation.

Comment: Updated the issue link to a more recent one that has a status of _Assigned_.